# Angular 11 all pages going to 404

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular for my new project and it has 3 modules so that I have decided to separate as 3 modules. This is my app routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutDefaultComponent, pathMatch: 'full', children: [
      { path: '', component: OverviewComponent },
    ]
  },
  // 404 Not Found page
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is working fine. After that I have create another module and its separate routes like below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'user',
    component: LayoutDefaultComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: UserOverviewComponen},
    ],
  },
];
```

This is user routing module and imported that in user module like below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CloudRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my user module

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
```

Here is my app.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    // Pages
    OverviewComponent,
    HelpCenterComponent,
    ChangelogComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    Ng2ChartsModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    TagInputModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    // App
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    // Auth Module
    AuthModule,
    // Apps
    UserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    Title,
    AppService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But If I click the user link that's automatically redirected to the 404 page. I am not able to find the issue. Could anyone help to fix issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your routes are calling two components with the same route, is it ok?

Comment: How you are defining your global routes between the two modules?

Comment: Can you add the app-routing.module in your question as well?

Comment: @GabrielSereno do you mean LayoutDefaultComponent?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed I have imported user module in app module

Comment: Please can you share your AppRoutingModule code?

Comment: @eko Already there. Could you please check top of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of wrong routing module import order. Put `AppRoutingModule` to the bottom

```js
    LayoutModule,
    // Auth Module
    AuthModule,
    // Apps
    UserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
```

If you put `AppRoutingModule` above any other module while it contains this line:

```js
{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
```

Angular router won't look at any other routes when this one matches and as you can guess, this will always match a url.

There's a section for this in the documentation which you can find here: https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order